# chef get converged-attributes without deploying

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, knife

We are using chef to deploy all of our stacks.

I need to build a runbook for each environment we deploy.
I have been parsing the environment, node and recipe files but the more information I need to extract, the more complex it becomes because I am converging the attributes in my application.

I would like to use the converged-attributes.json file produced by our chef deployment without deploying any code because we can't deploy production to the build runbooks.

We also plan to build the runbook before the environment exists to provide configuration information to the DevOps team (e.g. memory requirements, ports, etc.).

Is there a way to use any of the chef/knife components or libraries to do the following?

1. Converge the attributes for each node
2. Write the converged attributes to a location my application can access on Mac OSX.
3. Quit before attempting to access any servers

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the generic case. Chef is executable code at heart and the only way to fully compute the side effects is to actually execute it. This is what `chef-client` does, you can't "converge" the node externally so step 3 doesn't really make any sense. You could try to use Why Run mode but we really don't recommend it and are probably going to remove the feature as it does more harm than good most of the time. Roles and environments are static data so you can parse and manipulate those, but cookbooks are code and have to be run in-place to know exactly what they will do.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Since the servers may not be stood up yet, would it be possible to run it against a Vagrant box?

Comment: That's up to you and your recipe. Chef will happily run on anything but the attributes in the end might be different if, say, your recipes react automatically to the number of CPUs or amount of RAM.